# How can I var_dump $this?

Tags: php, debugging, this

I tried Googling/Search-engineing but the use of `$` seems to go amiss in most search algorithms.

I had a script within Magento2 that did this:

```
<?php
    echo '<pre>'. print_r($this, 1) .'</pre>';
```

Reloading the page gives me a memory leak error page, despite having *unlimited* limits within the .ini file.

Is there a proper way to display information about what `$this` currently refers to and what data it holds?

Comment: Did you tried with `var_dump($this);`

Comment: `$this` is the current object.

Comment: @executable I did indeedy :)

Comment: @Cid aware - I'm in a .phtml template file and would like to see what current object I'm in :)

Comment: I think the way Magento2 functions, plays a role in giving you that error. If you just execute it, you get a simple fatal error. https://3v4l.org/sKQ8E

Comment: @vivek_23 well yeah - it would fatal error, the code isn't in an object... o.O

Answer (score -1):

Referring to your comments, probably $this doesn't hold anything when you call it, so it may cause Limit Memory Crash.

**P.S.** Please be more specific and add some other code, so we can help you.

Comment: if it held nothing it wouldn't crash - there's nothing to add to the memory pool ...

Comment: But it always stop page from loading.

Comment: That's due to it having data in ... not because it has nothing. It would just return `(*null*)` or `(*empty*)` not a fatal error